# Time Limit Exceeded

Tags: c

Escrevi o código abaixo para a resolução do problema [1112](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1112) do site UriOnlineJudge e aparentemente a lógica empregada está perfeita, mas estou recebendo um erro de tempo excedido. Não estou conseguindo identificar o erro. Aparenta ser no primeiro scanf(), já que quando rodo o programa posso digitar uma sequência interminável de 0's e espaços que o programa só retornará zero e encerrará quando a tecla ENTER for pressionada, mas não sei o que fazer para ele, quando ler 3 zeros consecutivos na primeira entrada, já encerrar. Creio que seja necessário que, ao fazer a leitura desses três dados, mesmo sem o pressionamento da tecla ENTER, o programa já encerre se forem três zeros.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    int X, Y, P, Q;
    int i, j, k, l;
    char carac;
    while(1){
        scanf("%d %d %d", &X, &Y, &P);
        if(X==0 && Y==0 && P==0){
            return 0;
        }
        int campo[X][Y];
        for(i=0;i<X;i++){
            for(j=0;j<Y;j++){
                campo[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
        scanf("%d", &Q);
        int N=0, Z, W, qtd;
        for(i=0;i<Q;i++){
            qtd=0;
            scanf(" %c", &carac);
            if(carac=='A'){
                scanf("%d %d %d", &N, &X, &Y);
                campo[X][Y]+=N;
            }
            else{
                scanf("%d %d %d %d", &X, &Y, &Z, &W);
                for(j=X;j<=Z;j++){
                    if(Y>W){
                        l=Y;
                        Y=W;
                        W=l;
                    }
                    for(k=Y;k<=W;k++){
                        qtd+=campo[j][k];
                    }
                }
                printf("%d\n", qtd*P);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu abri o link, dei uma olhada no problema e notei que na parte superior da página há a indicação de um tempo limite máximo: "timelimit 4". Ou seja, provavelmente, o problema não esteja no código e você simplesmente tenha estourado o tempo para apresentar a solução.

Answer (score 2):

Verifica o valor devolvido pelos `scanf()`

```
        if (scanf("%d%d%d", &X, &Y, &P) != 3) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        if (scanf("%d", &Q) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

            if (scanf(" %c", &carac) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

                if (scanf("%d%d%d", &N, &X, &Y) != 3) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

                if (scanf("%d%d%d%d", &X, &Y, &Z, &W) != 4) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Antes do `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` podes mandar uma mensagem informativa para `stderr`, por exemplo: `fprintf(stderr, "Erro de input na linha %d\n", __LINE__);`

Comment: Isto ainda não resolve o problema. Preciso que, ao usuário digitar "0 0 0" nessa entrada, sem pressionar ENTER depois disso, o programa já reconheça os três valores. O único problema é que o scanf() está esperando por um ENTER do usuário, que não terá neste caso.

Comment: O input é *"line buffered"*; o que quer dizer que o Sistema Operativo (mais propriamente a biblioteca *runtime* do C) só liberta os dados juntamente com um ENTER. Não há volta (fácil) a dar a esta situação. Não acredito que o *online judge* esteja a contar com programas que funcionem sem o ENTER.